# Create attribute and Store it into a new variable in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a doubt. How can we create an attribute and store that attribute value in a variable so that the value can be re-used. And mainly the attribute must be created within a template.

> ```
> <xsl:template name="test">
> <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

I want to use the value of "id" at multiple locations of my xslt file.

Comment: The value of an attribute node generated with `generate-id()` is a string, if you want to store a string value you normally simply use `<xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>`. Your question is unclear, it is not clear whether you want to store an attribute node or a string value in a variable. And have you run into problems trying to reuse a variable value? Where did you declare, where did you try to use the variable?

Comment: I want to store "generate-id()" in a variable and I don't want to use the variable at the time when I call that specific template. 
ex:
>     <xsl:call-template name="test"/>

Comment: I want to store "generate-id()" in a variable and I don't want to use the variable at the time when I call that specific template. 
ex:
    <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
When i call the above template, the value of "generate-id()" will be stored and how can I be able to use this variable in other locations except call-template.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are immutable and a variable declared within a template is not visible outside that template. You're clearly trying to use the language in a way it isn't designed to be used; if you show us your problem, rather than your wrong approach to a solution, then we can help show you the right way to address it.

You use the phrase "at the time" in your comment - that's a clear indication that you're thinking in procedural rather than functional terms. There's no time axis in XSLT processing; things happen when the processor chooses to make them happen.